# concatenate string with hyphen in function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to hardcode a hyphen in my function and return the string, but I'm unable to build the syntax. Could you guys help me with the syntax?

```
NES_Person_ComputeInternalName_Internal(GetValue("FirstName").String, GetValue("LastName").String, _
                            Getvalue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456).string,GetValue("City").String, _dep, GetValue("personnelNumber").String )
```

I want the hyphen between:

`Getvalue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456).string, GetValue("City").String`

Answer (score 0):

If you just build the part you need altered and then add it as one of the parameters in the function, you'll still be able to access each one individually in the function as well as use the altered one there as needed as well.

```
Dim strBuilt as String = String.Empty

strBuilt = Getvalue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456).string & "-" & GetValue("City").String

NES_Person_ComputeInternalName_Internal(GetValue("FirstName").String, GetValue("LastName").String, Getvalue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456).string, GetValue("City").String, _dep, GetValue("personnelNumber").String, strBuilt)
```

Comment: @BajiSharian Happy to help. Thank us with upvotes and marking "best answer". :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NES_Person_ComputeInternalName_Internal` simply concatenates your strings (that might be incorrect), you could use string interpolation for better readability (and a slightly shorter piece of code):

```
Dim myString As String = $"{GetValue("FirstName").String}{GetValue("LastName").String}{GetValue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456).String}-{GetValue("City").String}{_dep}{GetValue("personnelNumber").String})
```

Depending on `GetValue`'s behaviour, you might even be able to leave out `.String`:

```
Dim myString As String = $"{GetValue("FirstName")}{GetValue("LastName")}{GetValue(uid_dialogcountry_iso3456)}-{GetValue("City")}{_dep}{GetValue("personnelNumber")})
```

String interpolation is great because it, er, interpolates the type of the inserted variables for you. You don't get to do any formatting with this form, though, so if you need that, you need to include `.ToString({StandardOrPredefinedStringFormat})`.